# Trying infinite while loop php

Tags: php, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to run an infinite while loop in php:

```
while($resultst = $sqlst -> fetch()){
$adlist = $resultst["Monday_Morning"];
echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
echo "<div>";
echo "<img src='/$adlist'>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

The code above loop through the result set once and stop, however the results are images which I need to loop continuously until refreshed with new images.

I know that

```
while(true){
//code to execute
}
```

will cause an infinite loop, but how do I implement the true into my code?

Comment: If you have infinite loop in PHP no results will be shown and your server/browser will hang. Are you sure that you want that effect?

Comment: It is better to try implementing a system based on events..

Comment: What do you mean with: "how do I implement the true into my code" ? You already made it correct. while(true), or while(1 == 1) ... or $tmp = true; while($tmp) ..

Comment: What I mean with"how do I implement the true into my code" is although the code runs correct, the loop stops after the first cycle. I need the loop to continue and start over. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop forever and will generate html but the generation will never stop and so, the user will never see the result:

```
while(true){
   if ($adlist = $resultst["Monday_Morning"]){
      echo "<div id='slideshow'>";
      echo "<div>";
      echo "<img src='/$adlist'>";
      echo "</div>";
   }
}
```

If you want to load new results you need to use Ajax or Ajax like mechanism and add new results to the DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to load the images into the slideshow div.
It will run in background without refreshing the page and will load the new images.
The existing above code will run and can create the overhead.

Comment: Many thanks. Will do that. However the loop should continue but it stops after the first cycle